# How to use the fcntl.h library in a class context?

Tags: c++, unix, serial-port, tty

I have a prototype code that goes as follows:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

const char* serial_port_path = "/tmp/respirator_back";
int serial_port = open(serial_port_path, O_RDWR);

char response [256];

int number;

int read_serial_until(char response[], char until_char, int serial_port, char buf = '\0', int n=0, int spot = 0){
  fd_set read_fds;

  struct timeval timeout;

  FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
  FD_SET(serial_port, &read_fds);

  timeout.tv_sec = 2;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;

  if (select(serial_port + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout) == 1)
  {
   while (true) {
     if (buf == until_char){
       break;
     }
     n = read(serial_port, &buf, 1);
     std::cout << buf;
     sprintf(&response[spot], "%c", buf);
     spot += n;
   }
  }
  else
  {
   std::cout<<"error or timed out" << std::endl;
  }
  return spot;
}

int main(){
  while (true){
    number = read_serial_until(response, '\n', serial_port);
    std::cout << number << std::endl;
  }
}
```

and it runs ok: it waits for 2 seconds for any info on the serial port, prints it or tells me that it timed out. The problem is when I try to use it in a class context. The select() function triggers, but doesn't time out.

I this context, there is a header with the class statements,

ventilator.hpp:

```
[...]
#include "serial_conf.hpp"

[...]

void Ventilator::serialHandler(Ventilator* v){

  fd_set read_fds;
  struct timeval timeout;

  FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
  FD_SET(serial_port, &read_fds);

  timeout.tv_sec = 1;
  timeout.tv_usec = 1000; // if data is incomplete, increase this value by 10%


  char data2send[150];
  int l_data2send;
  char data2send_reg[100];
  int l_data2send_reg;
  // std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t_elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t_now;
  // std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli> delta_t;
  int cont_reg_data = 0;
  char data_received[10];
  int len_data_received;

  while (true){
    serial_port = open(serial_port_path, O_RDWR);
    len_data_received = read_serial_until(data_received, '\n', serial_port, read_fds, timeout);
    close(serial_port);

[...]
```

and another header with read_serial_until() declaration:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>

//port settings
int serial_port;
const char* serial_port_path = "/tmp/respirator_back";

//utils
int read_serial_until(char response[], char until_char, int serial_port, fd_set read_fds, timeval timeout, char buf = '\0', int n=0, int spot = 0){

  if (select(serial_port + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout) == 1)
  {
    std::cout<<"reading serial port" << std::endl;
    while (true) {
      if (buf == until_char){
        break;
      }
      n = read(serial_port, &buf, 1);
      std::cout << buf;
      sprintf(&response[spot], "%c", buf);
      spot += n;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout<<"error or timed out" << std::endl;
  }
  return spot;
}
```

As mentioned before, it passes the if statement that contains the select(), but does not triggers the timeout. It stucks at "reading serial port". By starting the program over and over, sometimes it triggers an "error or timed out", and than stucks again reading the serial port.

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: thanks for the advice, working on a mre..